Mathematica can't handle expressions with Bessel functions in the limit of a large argument
Consider the following function:
f[s_,T_] = (9894.791629122174*Sqrt[1 - 0.07728400000000002/s]*Sqrt[1 - 0.0729/s]*
   Sqrt[s]*
      (0.056867000000000015 - 3*s)^2*BesselK[1, Sqrt[s]/T])/(T*
   BesselK[2, 0.139/T]^2)

It is defined in the range s $\in$ (0.077284, Infinity) and (ideally) arbitrary T > 0. For some reason, Mathematica fails to perform any calculations with this quantity for the values T < 10^-3:
f[s, 10^-4]


Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered.

Could you please tell me if it is possible to treat it in a proper way?

This is really a classical example of precision loss, which has been answered many times on this site, please look for similar questions and read How to | Control the Precision and Accuracy of Numerical Results. BesselK[2, 1000.] is 0.. If you want a different result, you have to use arbitrary-precision calculations, for example: N[BesselK[2, 1000], 5] or BesselK[2, 1000.`10].

@JohnTaylor Have a look at this Unable to plot Exp[-a Sqrt[1+x^2]] for a>700

You'll need to use arbitrary-precision or exact coefficients in f[s, t] in addition to s and t.

I though the first duplicate has a problem that is rarely encountered, but now I'm not so sure. I'm confused by a random bug (see that Q&A for my answer today). There may be an older post than @Ulrich's suggestion, but I went with adding it, since its focus is pratically identical to the issue here.

A simple way to replace parameters from machine precision numbers to exact numbers is adding /. a_?NumericQ :> Rationalize[a, 10*^-100] to your definition of f[s,T]:
Clear[f];

f[s_, T_] = (9894.791629122174*Sqrt[1 - 0.07728400000000002/s]*
     Sqrt[1 - 0.0729/s]*Sqrt[s]*(0.056867000000000015 - 3*s)^2*
     BesselK[1, Sqrt[s]/T])/(T*BesselK[2, 0.139/T]^2) /. 
  a_?NumericQ :> Rationalize[a, 10*^-100]

(*(11694960965 Sqrt[1 - 15977598708/(206738764919 s)] Sqrt[
 1 - 729/(10000 s)] (3853048140/67755431797 - 3 s)^2 Sqrt[s]
  BesselK[1, Sqrt[s]/T])/(1181931 T BesselK[2, 139/(1000 T)]^2)*)

f[s, 10^-4]

(*(116949609650000 Sqrt[1 - 15977598708/(206738764919 s)] Sqrt[
 1 - 729/(10000 s)] (3853048140/67755431797 - 3 s)^2 Sqrt[s]
  BesselK[1, 10000 Sqrt[s]])/(1181931 BesselK[2, 1390]^2)*)

N[f[10, 10^-4], 10]

(*9.545430208*10^-12515*)

